# How can I stop VS code from converting tabs to spaces in a particular file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

In the VS code editor, the default setting is to replace tabs by spaces, which is what I want. However, this is disastrous in a make file. I have written a make file (named `Makefile`) but VS code insists on changing tabs to spaces so I get a "Missing Separator" error when I run `make`.

If I go to File > Preferences > Settings and type `@id:editor.insertSpaces` in the menu, I see this:

[image: settings, editor: insert spaces, modified elsewhere]

When I click on *Modified elsewhere* I see this:

[image]

The second screenshot seems to says that the editor won't insert spaces in a Makefile, but it certainly is. What am I doing wrong, or what have I failed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifing `settings.json`

[VScode Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

[image: VScode JSON settings]

###### There are 3 levels (by higher priority)

1. Worspace Settings JSON
2. User Settings JSON
3. Default Settings JSON

This should fix most inconveniences:

```json
    "[markdown]": {
        "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
        "editor.insertSpaces": false
    },
```

Comment: You can also search from the settings GUI, like for example: `Insert Space @lang:markdown` Or by cliking the `filter` icon on the search bar all to the right.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I should have posted my solution, but I didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the following to `settings.json`:

```
"[makefile]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": false
    },
```